# Необходимо написать алгоритм для нахождения дельта Y для полинома Ньютона

Tags: c++, математика

Суть проблемы в том, что мне нужно для д/з сделать программу, которая будет считать полином Ньютона, но я уже не первый день ломаю голову над дельта Y, которая может быть создана при произвольном количестве узлов ( в данном случае i)[image: Таблица, позывающая зависимость дельта Y] по таким вот формулам она считатется:[image: формула для подсчёта дельта Y первой степени][image: формула для подсчёта дельта Y второй степени]
Ну и вот общая формула (в ней опечатка в пером Y, там индекс у Y не i-1, а i+1) 
[image: формула для подсчёта дельта Y k-той степени]
Вот мои попытки написать код:

```
//самая новая попытка
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            dY[i][0] = Y[i + 1] - Y[i];
            for (int k = 1; i < n - k; k++) {
                dY[i][k] = dY[i + 1][k - 1] - dY[i][k - 1];
            }

    for (int i = 0; i > n - 1; i++) {
            dY[i][0] = Y[i + 1] - Y[i];
            for (int l = 0; l < n - 2; l++) {
                dY[i][1] = dY[i + 1][0] - dY[i][0];
                for (int k = 2; i < n - k; k++) {
                    dY[i][k] = dY[i - 1][k - 1] - dY[i][k - 1];
                }
            }
        }
```

Ну и первые мои попытки:

```
dY[0][1] = Y[1] - Y[0];
    for (int l = 1; dY[n][n - 1] = NULL; l++) {
        for (int k = n; dY[n][n - 1] = NULL; k--) {
            dY[k - l][1] = Y[k] - Y[k - 1];
            dY[k - l + 1][2] = dY[k - 1][1] - dY[k - 2][1];
            dY[k - l + 2][3] = dY[k - 2][2] - dY[k - 3][2];
        }

    }
    for (int i = 0; i > n - 1; i++) {
        dY[i][0] = Y[i + 1] - Y[i];
        for (int l = 0; l < n - 2; l++) {
            dY[i][1] = dY[i + 1][0] - dY[i][0];
            for (int k = 2; i < n - k; k++) {
                dY[i][k] = dY[i - 1][k - 1] - dY[i][k - 1];

            }

        }
    }
```

Дельта Y я создавал через двумермый массив `dY[n][n-1]`, сам Y через одномерный размером n. Надеюсь на понимание, так как учусь сам, а в институте знаний дали только, чтобы Hello, World! вывести на QBasic. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Цикл работает при положительном условии: `for (int i = 0; i > n - 1; i++)` - не правильно, нужно : `for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)`

Comment: В цикле требуется условие , а вы делаете присваивание `for (int l = 1; dY[n][n - 1] = NULL; l++)`. В сравнении числа нужно использовать знак `==` или не равно `!=`: `for (int l = 1; dY[n][n - 1] != NULL; l++)`

Comment: Цикл проверки чисел на `NULL` работать всё равно не будет. Вы нигде в массив не записываете `NULL` и вообще этот тип не совместим с числами.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, про приравнивание и присваивание я ступил как видимо, да null это же отсутствие заполнения, разве нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Индексы строк не учитываете, в первом цикле выходите за пределы массива (может быть крах памяти), во втором - лишняя работа. Считайте внимательно индексы.

```
# include <cstddef>
# define datan ((size_t)5UL)
int main(){
  int matrix_dY[datan][datan];
  int vector_Y[datan]={};
  for (size_t i = datan-1;i;) {
    -- i;
    matrix_dY[i][0] = vector_Y[i + 1] - vector_Y[i]; }
  // столб 0 размер datan-1: индексы 0..datan-2
  // столб 1 размер datan-2: индексы 0..datan-3
  // столб k размер datan-1-k: индексы 0..datan-2-k
  size_t k = 1;
  while ( 1 + k < datan ) {
    for (size_t line = 0; line < datan-1-k; line++) 
      matrix_dY[line][k] = matrix_dY[line + 1][k - 1] -
                matrix_dY[line][k - 1];
    k++; }
  }
```

Comment: Ваш код сложноват для меня, а в особенности я не понимаю где datan должен брать значения и что это вообще(данные в переводе со Шведского=)?)

Comment: `datan` - это константа программы, зашитая в код. Я её определил с помощью `#define`. `(size_t)` - это приведение любого числа к нужному типу `size_t`.

Answer (score 2):

Собственно проблему решил таким вот кодом

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        dY[i][0] = Y[i + 1] - Y[i];
    }
    int k = 1;
    for (int l = 0; l < n - 1; l++) {
        for (int o = 0; o < n; o++) {
            dY[o][k] = dY[o + 1][k - 1] - dY[o][k - 1];
        }
        k++;
    }
```

этот код ещё нужно отредактировать и работает он не очень, но считает то, что надо